# AWS Lambda-to-Lambda parallel invocation has degraded performance compared to local parallel lambda invocation

Tags: python, aws-lambda

I have an "orchestrator" lambda which takes a list of parameters, and synchronously invokes a "worker" lambda for each parameter in that list. The orchestrator then waits for all of the worker lambdas to complete and returns the aggregate result. The orchestrator is passed a list containing 122 items, and I am encountering some strange behavior.

When I test the orchestrator lambda on my host machine, it works flawlessly, invoking all 122 worker lambdas in parallel and returning the result. It completes in about 1 minute, which is the same length of time as the longest individual worker invocation. This makes sense, as all lambdas are invoked in parallel.

But, when I run the orchestrator lambda in a lambda environment, it seems to run with degraded performance.  I captured performance metrics which indicate that the local version returns ~9 results/second, and the lambda-hosted version returns ~2 results/second. Please see the attached graphs which illustrate this.

Both my local host and lambda environment are running the same version of python (3.7.4), with 1.7GB memory and one full vCPU allocated to both orchestrator and worker lambdas. For reference, the code for the orchestrator lambda is [here](https://github.com/metabolize/werkit/blob/lambda-manager/werkit/aws_lambda/default_handler.py) and [here](https://github.com/metabolize/werkit/blob/lambda-manager/werkit/aws_lambda/parallel.py).

Local performance:

[image: Local invocation]

Lambda-hosted performance:

[image: Lambda-hosted performance]

What could explain this discrepancy in performance between the local and lambda-hosted versions?

Answer (score 1):

It seems the issue was in how I was using asyncio. I was invoking the worker lambda with the boto3 lambda client like this:

```
loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()  
await loop.run_in_executor(lambda_client.invoke, ...)
```

It appears this was blocking in the lambda environment, but not on my host machine, which led to degraded performance. I am not sure why.

I resolved this by refactoring my code to use the aioboto3 library, like this:

```
async with aioboto3.client('lambda') as lambda_client:
    response = await lambda_client.invoke(...)
```

This achieves the same performance in lambda as on my host machine.